# Can anyone help me understand why this Jquery works in Chrome but not in IE?

Tags: jquery

i've just spent the last 4 hours working on this piece of code and was so happy to finally get it working, but it wont work in IE!  I can't undersand why?

Here is the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hQkFH/8/

Thank you!!

Comment: Doesn't work well in chrome for me, either.  Why are you cloning and animating the clone?

Comment: What does *not work* mean in this case? Maybe `scrollHeight` is your problem: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t36

Comment: It doesn't work because it's IE.

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Good point TJ, will do in the future, I only linked to the sandbox because it easily encapsulates everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't exactly work well in Chrome. The problem that breaks it in Internet Explorer, however, is the trailing comma in the object literal:

```
$(this).clone().css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: offsetTop,
    left: offsetLeft, // <-- here
}).attr("id", "cloned").appendTo("body");
```

That syntax is valid, but causes an error in Internet Explorer before v9.